# Required document about apache cassandra thrift Api

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have tried to find out the document about cassandra thrift Api. But i did't get any reference document.

particularly i want know about org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Column.setTtl(int ttl) Api. here argument ttl refers to seconds or minutes or any other value ?

Please provided the reference link and so that it will be helpful for everyone.

Thnx

Answer (score 1):

It is in seconds. See t[his link for a blog post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-expiring-columns) about the deprecated thrift api.

And from the [specification](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API10), **ttl**, i32, "an optional, positive delay (in seconds) after which the Column will be automatically deleted".

Answer (score 0):

Here is Thrift API specification - http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API10